# How to check if an jQuery event is bound to an element from a cypress test

Tags: jquery, cypress

I am testing some code that uses jQuery to bind click events, and I am having a problem with the test running before the click event is bound.

I want to avoid putting arbitrary waits in the test, so I was trying to find some way to check if the event is bound, and then I can wait for this before making test assertions.

I came up with this super dirty approach in the console:

```
$._data($('.element-being-tested')[0], 'events' ).click[0].handler.toString().includes('something I know is in the function')
```

But I cant transfer this to cypress, because `Cypress.$._data()` doesn't exist.

How do check if a query event is bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly testing that the event exists, you could use Cypress retry-ability to keep testing the event's affect, something like

```
cy.get('.element-that-changes-after-event').then($target => {
  // use closure to get a reference to changing element

  cy.get('.element-being-tested')
    .should($clickable => {       // .should(cb) callback function will be retried

      $clickable.click()
      expect($target.text()).to.equal('Content that appears after click event')

    });

});
```

See [Assert class name contains heading-](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Assert-class-name-contains-heading)

There may be a simpler way to do this, please post your test.